# How can I produce black and white source code using the minted package?

Tags: minted

I just started using the minted package, to produce formatted source codes.

I thought the style bw is a black and white style of pygmentize and it just uses italic and bold to format the code (I tried  the code below), but I was wrong. Is there any way to produce formatted code which looks good in black and white?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
  \usemintedstyle{bw}
  \inputminted{bash}{sample.sh}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

The problem isn’t the style – `bw` is correct and works fine! – but the *font*. The default monospace font of LaTeX doesn’t support italics and bold.

You need to switch to a different font – e.g. by loading the `courier` package, or by using XeLaTeX and loading a custom font.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I could see, there's no predefined style to achieve the desired formatting; a list of predefined styles can be obtained by running

```
pygmentize -L styles
```

in a terminal.

You can define your own style, and instructions can be found in the website under [Creating Own Styles](http://pygments.org/docs/styles/#creating-own-styles).

Another option would be to use some of the options for the `\inputminted` command (or for the `minted` environment) to quickly get something like you want. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\inputminted[bgcolor=black,formatcom=\color{white}]{console}{sample.sh}

\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black,formatcom=\color{white}]{bash}
#! /bin/bash
# script to turn the screen blue
setterm -background blue
echo It is a blue day
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

and the file `sample.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
# script to turn the screen blue
setterm -background blue
echo It is a blue day
```

[image]

Comment: Not true -- `bw` is included by default.

Comment: @BenAlpert: Yes, of course, `bw` is included; all I said is that the style I thought the OP wanted was not one of the predefined ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}` in your preambule. I use this solution so as to have bold face when I use the `listings` package. This solution does not need to use the package `courrier`.

Comment: Please extend this answer to explain what is happening and how this would fix the issue. This way other users will have a better chance to understand the issue and solution.

Comment: I can do better...